# How to debug Google Identity Platform custom claims not working with Firebase database rules?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-admin

I have the following Rules for my Firebase Storage database:

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    allow write: if request.auth.token.role == "admin";
  }
}
```

With the following code, I have verified my UID has the admin role:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require('./key-file.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  projectId: "some-project-id",
});


const uid = 'my-uid';

admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    console.log(userRecord.customClaims);
  });
```

Sample output:

```json
{ role: 'admin' }
```

However, when my client (Dart code) tries to upload an image, it gets permission denied. Here's my upload code:

```dart
print('Current UID: ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}');
final testFileContent = Uint8List.fromList('This is a test file'.codeUnits);
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('test.txt').putData(testFileContent);
```

Logs:

```
I/flutter ( 7630): Current UID: X2vSwXi5PIeOWkQOCmXxvzqTPem2
E/StorageException( 7630): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 7630): User does not have permission to access this object.
```

Does anyone have better suggestions how to debug this?

I've done all the generic stuff like:

- Verified this is the correct project ID
- Verified it's the correct bucket (there's only one bucket)
- Waited an hour for things to propagate
- Logged out and back in

It would be great if I could see the custom claims of users on the Firebase console, or test them with Rules Playground, but that doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the question and answer in case someone else finds the same problem. The rules are missing a match on the path- they need to look like this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} { // You have to specify which path the rules apply to!
      allow write: if request.auth.token.role == "admin";
    }
  }
}
```

Note - When adding a claim to a user, i.e. with the following Javascript code:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./key-file.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  projectId: "some-project-id",
});


admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims("some-user-uid", {"claim1": "value2"});
```

The person with uid `some-user-uid` does have to logout and login again for the Database Rules to take effect.